# select all columns from both tables postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a simple sql join query

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM Orders a
JOIN Customers b ON a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
```

which selects all columns from both tables . I need to achieve the same in 
Postgresql function,but i am not able to select data from 2nd table

```
CREATE  FUNCTION get_data (p_pattern VARCHAR,p_year INT) 
 RETURNS TABLE (
orders.*,Customers.*
) 
AS $$
```

Comment: please elaborate the post. in function?.. what  exactly you do and what is the exact problem?

Comment: `select *` selects from all tables in the query in every DBMS I have ever used. Does PostGreSQL differ here? That seems weird/unlikely to me. And yes, "I am not able to X" is not a valid problem description.

Comment: Your function should return a `select` statement from the desired tables/columns, not just the table names. Also, presumably you really intend for the function arguments to be used in the `where` clause, as otherwise the function would not achieve anything useful.

Comment: what if my table has 100 columns??? this is not a viable solution for that

Comment: Read both of my comments on this post, and then combine them. You should be able to `select * from tblA inner join tblB on blah` and get all the columns just fine. You then need to incorporate that select into your function in a syntactically correct way, not what you've tried above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one problem is that neither function nor views can return the columns with same names (in your example columns `CustomerID` presented in both tables). And the another one - syntax:

> `RETURNS TABLE ( column_name column_type [, ...] )`

from the [official doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html), nothing about `table_name.*`.

Aside of the obvious solution where you specifying the complete list of columns, there is one trick with [composite (row, record)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) types:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION get_data (p_pattern VARCHAR,p_year INT) 
  RETURNS TABLE (order orders, customer customers) 
AS $$
```

Note that you can use table/view names as types in declarations.

And in that case your query could looks like

```
SELECT a, b
FROM Orders a
JOIN Customers b ON a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
```

After that the usage of the function would be:

```
select
  *, -- two composite columns
  (order).*, -- all columns from table orders
  (customer).*, -- all columns from table customers
  (order).CustomerID -- specific column from specific table  
from
  get_data(<parameters here>);
```

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=22579cc10b426ea6474cb010e399e6b1)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the columns are present on which you are joining, you can do this:

```
    SELECT * FROM Orders a,Customers b WHERE a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID;
```

For more see the official docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/tutorial-join.html

You can also refer this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_joins.htm
.It has good examples and references what joins are there in postgre and how to do them.

Comment: i need to select all columns from both tables as mentioned, this will only return columns from Orders table

Comment: According to the official docs, this query should do the trick and return all columns of both the tables.

Comment: @underscore_d I didn't mention that the syntax was discouraged. I just gave the summary of what was in the docs to do the required thing.

Comment: My point is that while explaining how to do something, you should follow established good practices, rather than recommending outdated, error-prone syntax.

Comment: @underscore_d Point accepted. But shouldn't the docs get updated to show which syntax is outdated or recommended. Anyways thanks for the update and info. I didn't know this before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148209/discussion-between-sumit-chakraborty-and-underscore-d).

Comment: No need, sorry, I didn't realise you had the 1st link, which does show the old syntax. I hadn't seen that link, only the 2nd one - which is better - and thought you just added the old join syntax yourself. The official docs are weird as they recommend the old syntax and then say `inner join` is just an 'alternative' and 'less used'. :S Nowdays, the reality is opposite.